# how to add string after splitting

Tags: java, file, split

The task that i had to do was to store the line from the file that contained "int" in it into a string array. the contents of the file are

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i=5;
    int j=9;
    int s,t;

    s=i+3;
    t=j+7;
    q=j+4;

    cout<<s<<t<<q;
}
```

But after running the following code instead of having the 3 int statements in it. the compiler only displays the last int line. how to get store the earlier lines?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        String[] myStringArray = new String[]{ };
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            File file = new File("123.txt");
            input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("int")){
                    myStringArray=line.split("[\\s,;]+");                    
                }
            }

            for(String a :myStringArray){
                System.out.println(a);
            }

            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe add spaces/tabs between numbers in `cout`?

Comment: @Lashane the C code should only be regarded as text, it's on the java code that he's got a problem.

Comment: @Aaron I mean `cout<<s<<t<<q;` will produce single line with `81613` in it, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lashane I believe he uses his java code to parse the c code itself rather than its output

Comment: @Aaron ah, got it, ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myStringArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(myStringArray,line.split("[\\s,;]+"));
```

You need to concatenate the next found 'int' to the end of your `myStringArray`.   Your code will overwrite `myStringArray` for every interation of the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure he wants to have all parts of each line in the same array. I'm wondering if he did not split the line by mistake so that the types would match

Comment: It sounds to me like he wants all three together "But after running the following code instead of having the 3 int statements in it. the compiler only displays the last int line. how to get store the earlier lines?".  His grammar isn't great and I have trouble understanding... So maybe you are right @Aaron

Comment: What I mean is that with your code he won't be able to distinguish which part belongs to which line. If I'm not mistaken, you produce the array `["int", "i=5", "int", "j=9", "int", "s" ,"t"]` while he may have preferred to have an array of arrays of words or just an array of the lines. Hard to say in the current state of the question indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`myStringArray=line.split("[\\s,;]+");` you replace the whole array there.